# history and cut command: get the second field

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cut

I am trying to get the commands from the history command.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-192:~/redacted$ history
 1  ls
 2  sudo apt-get install git -y
 3  git clone https://redacted@bitbucket.org/redacted/redacted.git
 4  ls
 5  cd redacted

ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-192:~/redacted$ history | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

No output. What's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

There are also spaces in the beginning of each row, so column 2 is most likely just another space. Since history's format is fixed, you could base your `cut` on the number of characters, like so:

```
[mureinik@computer /]$ history | cut -c8-
```

Answer (score 1):

Through sed,

```
history | sed 's/^ *[^ ]* *//'
```

It removes all the leading spaces along with the numbers.

Comment: How about my command " silly" (starting with a space) ?
How about indent with spaces for multi-line commands (ksh) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `cut` gets a space as field separator, defining each one of them a different field.

So whenever you have history as this:

```
1  ls
2  sudo apt-get install git -y
3  git clone https://redacted@bitbucket.org/redacted/redacted.git
4  ls
5  cd redacted
 ^
 what you get
```

When you do `cut -d' ' -f2` you get the space just after each number.

#### How can you solve it?

squeeze the spaces with `tr`:

```
history | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

use `awk` to print the second field. For `awk`, many fields do not count, so that the following will always print the second block of text:

```
history | awk '{print $2}'
```